# Recursive loop optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

Is there a way to rewrite my code to make it faster?

```
for i = 2:length(ECG)
    u(i) = max([a*abs(ECG(i)) b*u(i-1)]);
end;
```

My problem is the length of ECG.

Comment: should there be a '+' before 'b'?

Comment: No, everything is correct here.

Comment: It is unclear, is the problem that ECG is very large?

Comment: Yes. Consequently, I have to wait for my result more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Have you pre-allocated `u` by doing `u = zeros(size(ECG))`? That should be the first step. Also, how large is `ECG`, and what are the values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Oh, pre-allocation solved my problem. Thank you. Anyway, why is it important? If vector is shorter, everything works fine without pre-allocation.

Comment: A quick glance says you have a recursive algorithm.
A quick glance says u(i) may equal (b^(i-1))*a*ECG(0)
So there is no way of vectorizing your code. Depending on the properties of ECG, a and b, you may make it more efficient, but I can't help you there

Comment: You are welcome. I gave an explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Rasman You can sometimes "vectorize" recursive loops by filtering. It's not that simple in this case, because it's non-linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pre-allocate `u` like this

```
>> u = zeros(size(ECG));
```

or possibly like this

```
>> u = NaN(size(ECG));
```

or maybe even like this

```
>> u = -Inf(size(ECG));
```

depending on what behaviour you want.

When you pre-allocate a vector, MATLAB knows how big the vector is going to be and reserves an appropriately sized block of memory.

If you don't pre-allocate, then MATLAB has no way of knowing how large the final vector is going to be. Initially it will allocate a short block of memory. If you run out of space in that block, then it has to find a bigger block of memory somewhere, and copy all the old values into the new memory block. This happens every time you run out of space in the allocated block (which may not be every time you grow the array, because the MATLAB runtime is probably smart enough to ask for a bit more memory than it needs, but it is still more than necessary). All this unnecessary reallocating and copying is what takes a long time.

Comment: from max([a*abs(ECG(i)) b*u(i-1)]);, doesn't it means that u is already pre-allocate before the loop? If u wasn't pre-allocated already, there would be an error in the max function.

Comment: @m_power I expect that @user1729509 has only allocated `u(1)` before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are several several ways to optimize this `for` loop, but, surprisingly memory pre-allocation is not the part that saves the most time. By far. You're using [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to find the largest element of a 1-by-2 vector. On each iteration you build this vector. However, all you're doing is comparing two scalars. Using the two argument form of `max` and passing it two scalar is MUCH faster: 75+ times faster on my machine for large `ECG` vectors!

```
% Set the parameters and create a vector with million elements
a = 2;
b = 3;
n = 1e6;
ECG = randn(1,n);

ECG2 = a*abs(ECG); % This can be done outside the loop if you have the memory
u(1,n) = 0;        % Fast zero allocation
for i = 2:length(ECG)
    u(i) = max(ECG2(i),b*u(i-1)); % Compare two scalars
end
```

For the single input form of `max` (not including creation of random `ECG` data):

```
Elapsed time is 1.314308 seconds.
```

For my code above:

```
Elapsed time is 0.017174 seconds.
```

FYI, the code above assumes `u(1) = 0`. If that's not true, then u(1) should be set to it's value after preallocation.